# (Perl) How to turn string into date format and find most recent?

Tags: linux, perl

I'm using Perl and have an input file with multiple dates such as 17/04/2021 written in it as text.
How could I go about turning them into date formats and then comparing them to see which one is the most recent?

Input file format:

```
01/09/2020
23/10/2019
12/06/2022
15/08/2017
```

Perl Script:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $InputFile = "path/to/file.input";
open(FH, '<', $InputFile) or die $!;
while(my $Line = <FH>)
{

}
close(FH);
```

Thanks.

Comment: or just use sort: `<inputfile sort -t/ -n -k3 -k2 -k1 | tail -1`

Answer (score 6):

Dates in the format `yyyymmdd` can be compared directly, numerically or lexically. So turn it around

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
# use List::Util qw(max);

die "Usage: $0 file\n" if not @ARGV;

my @dates;

while (<>) {
    chomp;

    push @dates, join '', reverse split '/';
}

@dates = sort { $a <=> $b } @dates;  # latest: $dates[-1]

say for @dates;

# Or, if only the last one is needed (uncomment 'use' statement)
# my $latest_date = max @dates;
```

The ["diamond operator" `<>`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#I/O-Operators) reads line by line files submitted on the command line, when used in scalar [context](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Context).  The [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split) argument for the separator is still a regular expression, even as I use `''` delimiters (instead of `/\//`). Its next (optional) argument, an expression yielding the string to split, is by default [`$_` variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$_).
Also see
[reverse](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reverse),
[join](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join),
[sort](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort), and [List::Util](https://perldoc.perl.org/List::Util), as needed.

Can do it in a commnad-line program ("one-liner") as well

```
perl -wnlE'push @d, join "", reverse split "/"; }{ say for sort @d' file
```

where `}{` stands for the beginning of `END { }` block. Or, for the latest date only

```
perl -MList::Util=max -wnlE'... }{ say max @d' file
```

---

If you'd like it more compact,

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

say for sort map { chomp; join '', reverse split '/' } <>;
```

That same diamond operator in the list context returns all lines at once, and here its output is fed to [map](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map) and that imposes the list context.

Or on the command line

```
perl -wE'say for sort map { chomp; join "", reverse split "/" } <>' file
```

Comment: If only max is needed, no need to store the array at all: eg. `$max=$cur if $cur>$max`

Comment: @jhnc Yeah, true -- but then I do need to have `$cur`variable floating around needlessly (or to add yet more, a `do` block), and things turn a bit lower-level.  (Also, I don't think it would gain us speed, expect perhaps for really small list?)  But yes, it's an option

Comment: I was thinking similarly, but with a regex to bust up and rebuild the date -- `reverse split` is pretty crafty.

Comment: @JimDavis Doable by all means, but the best I can do is `m{[^/]+}g` to return the list of non-`/` words, and then still need `join '', reverse` on that. In order to build the output string entirely in the regex I think we'd need to spell out all three subpatterns and then it gets cumbersome.  (A single pattern cannot _capture_ all that it matched and so we can't glue them backwards in the replacement part)

Comment: In other words, it can't match all instances of a single pattern scattered around the string in one pop, so to be able to then use them together in the replacement side.   It goes and matches one by one and in a `s///` operator the replacement side then runs for each one at a time, or in a match operator it scoopes it all and _returns_ them, outside of regex. A little bummer that we can't get all that a single pattern matched to work with in the replacement side :(

Comment: @zdim I was thinking something basic like `s{(\d\d)/(\d\d)/(\d\d\d\d)}{$3$2$1}`, but to clarify: I meant "crafty" as compliment. :)

Comment: @JimDavis Yes, I got it -- thank you very much for nice words :).  As for the regex you show, yeah that takes care of it all. I just wish we could say _'match this pattern everywhere and then give me all that in the replacement side'_. (Just btw, note that `\d` matches all unicode "digits", some 700-800 chars. But with `/a` it takes only `0-9` -- but then a few other common patterns only do ASCII)

Answer (score 4):

`strptime` is (always) your friend:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.12.10;
use Time::Piece;

my $fmt='%d/%m/%Y';
my @t;
while( <DATA> ){
    chop;
    eval { push @t, Time::Piece->strptime($_, $fmt) } or
        say STDERR "Unexpected format in input: $_";
}

say $_->strftime($fmt) foreach sort @t;

__DATA__
01/09/2020
01/09/2020
23/10/2019
12/06/2022
15/08/2017
```

To do this as a one-liner, you can do:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -0777 -aE '$f="%d/%m/%Y";
    say foreach sort { $a <=> $b } map Time::Piece->strptime($_, $f), @F'
```

The one-liner is not quite the same, though as it will handle multiple dates on a line while the script is strict about each line containing only one date.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use Time::Local;

my $InputFile = $ARGV[0];
open(my $fh, '<', $InputFile) or die $!;

## A hash to hold the times so we can sort later
my %seconds;

while(my $Line = <$fh>){
  chomp($Line);
  my ($day, $month, $year) = split(/\//, $Line);
  my $secondsSinceTheEpoch = timelocal(0, 0, 0, $day, $month-1, $year);
  $seconds{$secondsSinceTheEpoch}++
}
close($fh);

my @sortedSeconds = sort {$a <=> $b} keys(%seconds);
print "$sortedSeconds[0]\n";
```

Or, if you're into the whole brevity thing:

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use Time::Local;

## A hash to hold the times so we can sort later
my %seconds;

while(<>){
  chomp();
  my ($day, $month, $year) = split(/\//);
  $seconds{timelocal(0, 0, 0, $day, $month-1, $year)}++
}

my @sortedSeconds = sort {$a <=> $b} keys(%seconds);
print "$sortedSeconds[0]\n";
```

In both cases, you need to pass the file to the script as an argument:

```
$ foo.pl file
1502744400
```